# How to identify overfitting in LSTM-RNN using metrics?

Tags: long-short-term-memory

How can I identify overfitting on a RNN-LSTM with the following metrics: RMSE, MSE, RAE, R-squared ? I have searched papers and google results. I don't see something clear to my mind. Also I rarely see some thresholds in RMSE, for example, that above x value it means that I have overfitting...

Comment: What do you want to train with your LSTM-RNN?

Comment: Time-series forecasting on temperature...

Comment: I see. Do you use other data other than temperature for the training such as location, date, time, and etc?

Comment: No, only temperature...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused, here are some facts about overfitting:

- Overfitting is only evaluated on the loss used to train the model.
- Overfitting depends on the difference between training loss and validation/test loss, not on a specific threshold, you should evaluate a plot of train/val loss across epochs during training.
- Overfitting is not detectable on metrics. Only on the loss.

So you cannot use any of the metrics you mentioned to detect overfitting, unless they are actually the loss used to train the model. Also a threshold for RMSE does not make sense to detect overfitting, it simply does not work that way.

Comment: I use loss function, and the both validation and training loss have almost the same values: ```Epoch 1/100
1640/1640 - 24s - loss: 0.0150 - val_loss: 7.6152e-04 - 24s/epoch - 2ms/step
Epoch 2/100
1640/1640 - 22s - loss: 2.6332e-04 - val_loss: 6.1577e-04 - 22s/epoch - 2ms/step``` So, because it confused me I am trying different methods of identifying the overfitting...

Comment: @just_learning These results do not show overfitting, so nothing to worry.